# getaddrinfo - results differ for numeric vs. named service

Tags: c, unix, getaddrinfo

I have a question about the behavior of getaddrinfo(), which seems to depend on how the service argument is specified. Specifying the service as a name causes getaddrinfo() to use getservbyname() to query the /etc/services database, but specifying the service numerically apparently results in no such query, and this can lead to differences in the results.

For example, specifying service = "5672" (the port for amqp), returns a list of addrinfo structures for the protocols IPPROTO_TCP, IPPROTO_UDP, and IPPROTO_IP, while specifying service = "amqp", returns a list of addrinfo structures for the protocols IPPROTO_TCP, IPPROTO_UDP, and IPPROTO_SCTP.

Why doesn't getaddrinfo() query the /etc/services database when the service is specified numerically? Thanks for any help.

Update:
Turns out that this is simply how getaddrinfo() is designed to handle the service parameter. If you know the port number, great. If you only know the service name getaddrinfo() will look up the port number for you.

The real issue for me then is that, even though SCTP is installed on my system (Ubuntu 16.04), getaddrinfo() does not return addrinfo structures with IPPROTO_SCTP. Looking at the source for getaddrinfo() it looks like it returns addrinfo structures for all the protocols it knew about **at the time it was built** rather that at the time is was called.

I think I may need to rebuild glibc to get a version of getaddrinfo() that supports SCTP. Can anyone confirm or correct my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a lot of code that assumes protocol = 0 and type = SOCK_STREAM **means** TCP. If getaddrinfo() returns addrinfo structures with IPPROTO_SCTP, this code breaks. The compromise solution (at least for FreeBSD and linux), has been to continue to have getaddrinfo() return only IPPROTO_TCP addrinfo structures for protocol = 0 and type = SOCK_STREAM. Anyone wanting getaddrinfo() to return addrinfo structures with IPPROTO_SCTP should specify ai_protocol = IPPROTO_SCTP in the hints. This only applies when the service arg is specified as a number; services specified as a name will cause getaddrinfo() to consult the /etc/services database and the protocol specified in the results will be based on what was found there.